# Dynamically change elements offset basing on it's own size and current offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element in a DIV. Like below...

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Normally to center the child in the middle of the parent while the child changes size(zoom), I would just do...

```
$('#child').resizable({
        resize:function(){
            // this extends the left/top offset while width increases
            $('#child').css({
                left:$('#parent').width()/2 - $('#child').width()/2,
                top:$('#parent').height()/2 - $('#child').height()/2
            })
        }
    });
```

The example above works perfectly fine but when am resizing the child, It always starts from the same spot not the child's offset.

But now i need to adjust the child's left and top offset just like the example above but this time not basing calculations on the parent's size but rather the exact offset of the child and its size.

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Comment: I gave u a votes up but your answer is based on CSS, I needed a JavaScript solution. I finally got it by increasing the elements width and then adjusting it's left offset by adding the width difference to the current left. This can be guaranteed to work in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you use `transform` and `transform-origin`.

`transform` use the elements own properties it's applied to, not the parent.

CSS Hover

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
}
#child {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform-origin: center top;        /* which origin to scale from */
}
#child:hover {
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

jQuery Hover

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#child").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("transform", "translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.5)");
  }, function() {
    $(this).css("transform", "translate(-50%,-50%)");
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
}

#child {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: center top;          /* which origin to scale from */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now how would i pragmatically do that in JavaScript..?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me but by pragmatically i meant without using css but the updated answer is pretty much the same as the first one since you are handing over the same style properties to the element.  I need to do some calculations note just css. But thanks for trying for me.

Comment: @Dennisrec Since I don't know what calculations you intend to do, I couldn't possible add them into the mix, though with the given answer I can't see how that should be any problem for you

Comment: Ok since i have your attention now, let me add a jfiddle for you and see. The target achievement i want is that when u are resizing a div element, that element for example its width, the offset left will reduce while it becomes bigger and when u decrease its size the offset left will also be decreasing. Like facebook dp changer, it's like a zoom.

Comment: @Dennisrec Please do...I will be busy for a while from now, but will have a look later, and keep you posted